# Java - OpenID (Login with Steam)

Tags: java, servlets, openid, steam, jopenid

I have recently had to some trouble trying to get OpenID to work in Java (servlet). I'm trying to make a user able to login to my website using their Steam account. I've tried mutliple libraries but some of them are outdated and for others is almost no documentation available so the library I'm trying right now is JOpenID. It works as expected until I need to verify the information sent back by Steam (http://steamcommunity.com/openid). This is my Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private OpenIdManager manager;

static final long ONE_HOUR = 3600000L;
static final long TWO_HOUR = ONE_HOUR * 2L;
static final String ATTR_MAC = "openid_mac";
static final String ATTR_ALIAS = "openid_alias";

public LoginServlet() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    manager = new OpenIdManager();
    manager.setRealm("http://localhost:8080/TestServletProject/LoginServlet");
    manager.setReturnTo("http://localhost:8080/TestServletProject/LoginServlet?login=verify");
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    if(login != null){
        if(login.equals("steam")){
            out.print("<h2>Redirecting</h2>");
            Endpoint endpoint = manager.lookupEndpoint("http://steamcommunity.com/openid");
            Association association = manager.lookupAssociation(endpoint);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTR_MAC, association.getRawMacKey());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTR_ALIAS, endpoint.getAlias());
            String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(endpoint, association);
            response.sendRedirect(url);
        }else if(login.equals("verify")){
             checkNonce(request.getParameter("openid.response_nonce"));
             byte[] mac_key = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(ATTR_MAC);
             String alias = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(ATTR_ALIAS);
             Authentication authentication = manager.getAuthentication(request, mac_key, alias);
             response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
             showAuthentication(response.getWriter(), authentication);
             return;
        }else if(login.equals("logout")){
            out.print("<h2>Loggin out</h2>");
        }
        return;
    }
    String id = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("steamid");
    if (id != null) {
        out.print("<h2>Welcome ");
        out.print(id);
        out.print("</h2>");
        out.print("<a href=\"LoginServlet?login=logout\">Logout</a>");
    } else {
        out.print("<a href=\"LoginServlet?login=steam\">Login</a>");
    }        
}

void showAuthentication(PrintWriter pw, Authentication auth) {
    pw.print("<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><title>Test JOpenID</title></head><body><h1>You have successfully signed on!</h1>");
    pw.print("<p>Identity: " + auth.getIdentity() + "</p>");
    pw.print("<p>Email: " + auth.getEmail() + "</p>");
    pw.print("<p>Full name: " + auth.getFullname() + "</p>");
    pw.print("<p>First name: " + auth.getFirstname() + "</p>");
    pw.print("<p>Last name: " + auth.getLastname() + "</p>");
    pw.print("<p>Gender: " + auth.getGender() + "</p>");
    pw.print("<p>Language: " + auth.getLanguage() + "</p>");
    pw.print("</body></html>");
    pw.flush();
}

void checkNonce(String nonce) {
    // check response_nonce to prevent replay-attack:
    if (nonce==null || nonce.length()<20)
        throw new OpenIdException("Verify failed.");
    // make sure the time of server is correct:
    long nonceTime = getNonceTime(nonce);
    long diff = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - nonceTime);
    if (diff > ONE_HOUR)
        throw new OpenIdException("Bad nonce time.");
    if (isNonceExist(nonce))
        throw new OpenIdException("Verify nonce failed.");
    storeNonce(nonce, nonceTime + TWO_HOUR);
}

private Set<String> nonceDb = new HashSet<String>();

// check if nonce is exist in database:
boolean isNonceExist(String nonce) {
    return nonceDb.contains(nonce);
}

// store nonce in database:
void storeNonce(String nonce, long expires) {
    nonceDb.add(nonce);
}

long getNonceTime(String nonce) {
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .parse(nonce.substring(0, 19) + "+0000")
                .getTime();
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
        throw new OpenIdException("Bad nonce time.");
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting a `org.expressme.openid.OpenIdException: Invalidate handle` on line 65: `Authentication authentication = manager.getAuthentication(request, mac_key, alias);`

While doing some research I found out that this had to do with the `Assosiaction` sent to steam being expired. This is the JOpenID class that causes the `OpenIdException`: https://github.com/michaelliao/jopenid/blob/master/src/main/java/org/expressme/openid/OpenIdManager.java

Does anybody know how I can get this to work, or alternatively, know a better library to use. I'm quite new to this and I'm not sure if I'm using the right library or if there's better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

So for anyone still wondering: I looked into the `JOpenID` code and it seems like the code in the `getAuthentication()` method that goes before the code that throws the exception is enough to retrieve the Steam ID (which is what I tried to get from Steam). So instead of `Authentication authentication = manager.getAuthentication(request, mac_key, alias);` I now just put `String identity = request.getParameter("openid.identity");`. This returns `http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561198206376959`, last part being the Steam ID.